# How were fish formed? Did Adam name them?

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, creation, fish, adam

Animals (including birds) are formed from the dust of the ground in Bereshit 2:19, and Adam gave them names according to verse 20.

But what about the fish (animals of the sea)? Are they also formed from the dust (smallest building blocks) of the earth? Did Adam name them? They're not mentioned in the narrative, and they're not mentioned in the Mabul narrative either, why?

Answer (score 7):

There are three parts to your question, however I am only answering the second and third part.

Regarding whether the fish were named by Adam. [Likutei Sichos 35 page 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14958&st=&pgnum=15) mentions a dispute in this matter. The source of this dispute is [the top Tosfiyos Chulin 66b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9615&st=&pgnum=134)

Regarding the fish at the Mabul [Rashi - Braishis 7:22](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39996&st=&pgnum=55) says that the fish did not die by the Mabul.

Answer (score 3):

Being that Gershon answered part two and three, I'll answer part one from the Talmud in [Chulin 27b](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Chullin.pdf) concerning ritual slaughter.

A Galilean travelling lecturer expounded: Cattle were created out of the dry earth and are rendered fit by the cutting of both organs; fish were created out of the water and are rendered fit without any ritual slaughtering; birds were created out of the alluvial mud and are therefore rendered fit by the cutting of one organ. R. Samuel of Cappadocia said: You can prove this from the fact that birds have scales on their legs like the scales of fishes.

Comment: If I remember that gemara correctly there is a dispute on how this drasha was said,and after the fact isn't there a shitta that it wasn't really the true pshat but just a dochek?