# Why didn't Adam name fish and insects?

Tags: names, animals, adam, genesis-bereishith

When Adam named animals, the Torah mentions three categories: cattle, wild animals, and birds:

> "וַיִּקְרָא הָאָדָם שֵׁמוֹת לְכָל־הַבְּהֵמָה וּלְעוֹף הַשָּׁמַיִם וּלְכֹל חַיַּת הַשָּׂדֶה..."
> "And Adam gave names to all the cattle and to the birds of the sky and to all the wild beasts..." [Genesis.2.20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.20)

How didn't it mention fish and insects, such as the locust or the Leviathan?

Comment: My feeling is they are lower life forms that do not need to all have individual names.

Comment: This might answer your question, especially on what the Rebbe says in Likkutei Sichos: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57592/27180

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14958&st=&pgnum=15

Comment: @Shmuel Very interesting, thank you.\

Comment: @Deuteronomy Yes